# Get latest inserted records Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am storing multiple posts in a model like:

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
   $post = new Post;
   $post->user_id = $user->id;
   $post->save();
}
```

Now if I have `20 users` I will have `20 new Posts`,

**Question:**

How do I get the 20 posts back after `save()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of inserted posts like this:

```
$posts = [];
foreach($users as $user) {
   $post = new Post;
   $post->user_id = $user->id;
   $post->save();
   $posts[] = $post;
}
```

You also can convert it to a collection after the `foreach` loop:

```
$posts = collect($posts);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
$rsltPosts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')
               ->limit(20)
               ->get();
```