# Laravel safely retrieve the last inserted record

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm saving an order into my database, once the order is saved I want to grab that order ID to pull up the order information on the confirmation screen.

It's important that the most recent order id is the one that's just been saved. If two or more orders are placed at once how can you ensure the correct ID is retrieved. Is it possible that slow server response time could cause this to fail?

Currently, I've found you can do the following;

```
$order = new Orders([
    'billing_name'          => $request->input('billing-name'),
    'billing_company'       => $request->input('company-name'),
    'billing_job_title'     => $request->input('job-title'),
    'billing_phone'         => $request->input('billing-phone'),
    'billing_email'         => $request->input('billing-email'),
    'billing_address_1'     => $request->input('billing-address-1'),
    'billing_address_2'     => $request->input('billing-address-2'),
    'billing_town'          => $request->input('billing-town'),
    'billing_county'        => $request->input('billing-county'),
    'billing_postcode'      => $request->input('billing-postcode'),
    'payment_status'        => 'Pending',
]);  

$order->save();
$recentOrder = $order->id;
```

I want to use the recently saved ID Further down in my controller for another query.

Comment: Can you access this `$order` variable on the confirmation screen? Or is it a new page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get latest inserted records Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172348/get-latest-inserted-records-laravel)

Comment: http://www.tutoriallaravel.com/laravel-example/laravel-5-ways-to-get-last-inserted-id

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir returning to a page/route. For other comments, I understand how to retrieve the last ID in the database the question is more aimed at security in terms of ensuring the last ID is actually the ID I want.

Comment: @SamXronn: I made an important update to my answer, please take a look. Don't add the order id to the URL!

Answer (score 1):

**You can't reliably get the id from the database after redirecting to a new page.**

You have to save it somewhere, preferably in the user's session:

```
session(['orderId' => $order->id]);
```

Then retrieve it on the confirmation page:

```
$order = Order::find(session('orderId'));
```

*(Unfortunately, I previously suggested to add the order id to the url. That's obviously extremely insecure, since a sequential id is trivial to guess for anyone.)*

Comment: this is unaccurate and off-topic

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear I want to access the id within the same controller immediately after the save. The ID is then passed to other functions, and ultimately returned to another view

Comment: Can't you just pass `$order` as a parameter?
`$this->yourMethod($order)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Transactions` in laravel, to ensure your queries aren't executed like exactly in the same time, it's like you ensure that when a transaction is treated, the other one won't until the previous one is finished....

To use transactions, wrap your code inside `DB::transaction` 
here is how you can do it:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    // you can use this if you don't have the last_order's ID
    $last_row = DB::table('orders')->latest()->first();
    // or you get your ID from the Create operation as you did.
});
```

Comment: [No need for another query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172348/get-latest-inserted-records-laravel#answer-49172383)

Comment: I mentioned this in case someone doesn't have the ID from an Insert operation ;)

Comment: @Sletheren so if I retrieved the last ID in the DB inside a transaction, other orders would be stalled? while the code from other customers executes. I understand we're talking times of 250ms or so?

Comment: The transaction doesn't help. There can still be new orders in the time between saving the order and beginning the transaction.

Comment: yes exactly, it's using the `Deadlocks` mechanism, where when an operation is treated the other will need to have these finished, it doesn't affect performance though

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir all the operations should pass from a transaction, therefore, the case u mentioned won't be a problem, because every creation, delete or update for sensible data are meant to be executed in such context, many banking projects I've worked on use the technique

Comment: It only works if you put `$order->save()` into the transaction, but that's not possible in this situation.

Comment: it's possbile, you should wrap up the code inside the transaction, and voilà!

Comment: It's not possible because the user is redirected to the confirmation page after the order is created. The question is about getting the id on the confirmation page.